# how can i change image size in my PieChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndoridcharts on my android app. My icons look too big inside the PieChart. Can't find the way make it smaller.

I was trying to use `pic.setBound()`. But its not worked for me(

All code here:

```
 fun updatePieChart(list: List<BudgetItem>, pieChart: PieChart, context: Context) {
        var expenses = 0F
        val expenseEntry: ArrayList<PieEntry> = ArrayList()
        val categories = list.groupBy { it.category.name }

        for (cats in categories) {
            var pic = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.incomes_money_48)
            for (i in cats.value) {
                expenses += i.cost
                pic = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, i.category.pic)

            }
            pic?.setTint(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.secondary_text))
            pic?.setBounds(0,0,20,20)

            //pic.alpha = 100
            //expenseEntry.add(PieEntry(expenses,cats.key))
            expenseEntry.add(PieEntry(expenses, cats.key, pic))

            Log.i("CatPic", "$pic")
        }
        val pieDataSet = PieDataSet(expenseEntry,"")

        pieDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS, 100)
       // pieDataSet.setDrawIcons(false)
        var pieData = PieData(pieDataSet)
        pieChart.setData(pieData)
        pieChart.legend.formSize = 12f
        pieChart.setDrawEntryLabels(false)
        pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(R.color.accent_orange)
        pieChart.data.setValueTextSize(14f)
        pieChart.legend.textSize = 14f
        pieChart.description.isEnabled = false
        pieChart.centerText = "Расходы"
        pieChart.invalidate()
    }
```

[image: pie chart picture]

Comment: Hi, could you add the relevant code snippets used to display the pie chart as well as the ways you have tried to make the icons smaller?

Comment: added my code, pal

Answer (score 0):

Well, MPAndroidChart draws icons at exact size (from Drawable's `getIntrinsicWidth()` and `getIntrinsicHeight()`). `pic.setBounds()` doesn't change IntrinsicWidth and IntrinsicHeight so it doesn't help.
You should create new Drawable for chart at your desire.